# quiero que me indique el promedio y me diga que el promedio fue menor o mayor que el anterior mes

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlprocedure

```
delimiter // 

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_promdio_venta(IN _fecha1 date, IN _fecha2 date )
BEGIN
    DECLARE LOCAL int;

DECLARE promedio int;

SET
LOCAL = promedio;

SET
promedio =(
SELECT
    avg(Valor_Venta)
FROM
    ventas
WHERE
    FechaYHora BETWEEN _fecha1 AND _fecha2);

SELECT
    Valor_Venta,
    FechaYHora,
    promedio
FROM
    ventas
WHERE
    FechaYHora BETWEEN _fecha1 AND _fecha2
HAVING
    Valor_Venta >= ANY (
    SELECT
        promedio
    FROM
        ventas
    WHERE
        FechaYHora BETWEEN _fecha1 AND _fecha2 );

IF promedio < LOCAL THEN
SELECT
    Valor_Venta,
    FechaYHora,
    'El promedio fue menor' AS promdedio
FROM
    ventas
WHERE
    FechaYHora BETWEEN _fecha1 AND _fecha2;
ELSE
SELECT
    Valor_Venta,
    FechaYHora,
    'El promedio fue mayor' AS promdedio
FROM
    ventas
WHERE
    FechaYHora BETWEEN _fecha1 AND _fecha2;
END IF;
END //
```

Comment: qué error tienes?

Comment: Entonces, busca el promedio del mes anterior, el del mes en revisión, los comparas con operadores lógicos y usas un if para decir lo que quieres decir

Comment: pero ese campo promedio no existe en la tabla como hago para guardar ese promedio

Comment: Dentro del procedimiento puedes crear una variable local que reciba el cálculo. Revisa la documentación sobre procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: no se como darle formato esto

Comment: alguien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es comparar el promedio del último mes con el anterior, prueba así:

```
SELECT IF(
    (
      SELECT AVG(Valor_Venta) FROM ventas
        WHERE FechaYHora BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND NOW()  
    )>(
      SELECT AVG(Valor_Venta) FROM ventas
        WHERE FechaYHora BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    ),'El promedio fue mayor','El promedio fue menor'  
  );
```

Y evitarás el procedimiento almacenado. Estoy suponiendo que tu tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas(
  FechaYHora datetime,
  Valor_Venta float
  );
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: me sale eso lo que acabe de publicar